# Proof of Laplace transform of real number powers: $\mathcal{L} \{ t^n \} = \frac{n!}{s^{n + 1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, induction, laplace-transform, alternative-proof

As I understand it, the theorem and proof for the Laplace transform of positive integer powers is as follows:

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $t^n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $t$ to the $n$th power for some $n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ge 0}$
>
> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the Laplace transform.
>
> Then
>
> $$\mathcal{L} \{ t^n \} = \dfrac{n!}{s^{n + 1}}$$
>
> for $\Re(s) > 0$
>
> **Proof**
>
> The proof proceeds by induction on $n$ for $t^n$.
>
> Base case:
>
> When $n = 0$, we have
>
> $$t^0 = 1$$
>
> \begin{align*} 
> \therefore \mathcal{L} \{ t^0 \} &= \mathcal{L} \{ 1 \} \\\
> &= \dfrac{1}{s} \ \ \ \text{(Laplace transform of a constant.)} \\\
> &= \dfrac{0!}{s^{0 + 1}} \ \ \ \text{(By the definition of $0!$.)}
> \end{align*}
>
> Induction Hypothesis:
>
> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \ge 1$.
>
> Then
>
> $$\mathcal{L} \{ t^n \} = \dfrac{n!}{s^{n + 1}}$$
>
> Induction Step:
>
> $$\mathcal{L} \{ t^{n + 1} \} = \int_0^\infty t^{n + 1} e^{-st} \ dt \ \ \ \text{(By the definition of Laplace transform.)}$$
>
> We now use integration by parts, which says that
>
> $$\int fg' = fg - \int f'g \ dt$$
>
> Let $f = t^{n + 1}$ and $g' = e^{-st}$
>
> Therefore, $f' = (n + 1)t^n$ and $g = - \dfrac{1}{s} e^{-st}$
>
> So we have
>
> $$\int t^{n + 1} e^{-st} \ dt = - \dfrac{t^{n + 1}}{s}e^{-st} + \dfrac{n + 1}{s} \int t^n e^{-st} \ dt$$
>
> Evaluating $t = 0$ and $t \to \infty$, we get
>
> \begin{align*} \mathcal{L} \{ t^{n + 1} \} &= \left. - \dfrac{1}{s} t^{n + 1}e^{-st} \right|_0^\infty + \dfrac{n + 1}{s} \mathcal{L} \{ t^n \} \\
> &= \left. -\dfrac{s^{-1}t^{n + 1}}{e^{st}} \right|_0^\infty + \dfrac{n + 1}{s} \mathcal{L} \{ t^n \} \\
> &= 0 - 0 + \dfrac{n + 1}{s} \mathcal{L} \{ t^n \} \\
> &= \dfrac{n + 1}{s} \times \dfrac{n!}{s^{n + 1}} \\
> &= \dfrac{(n + 1)!}{s^{n + 1 + 1}}
> \end{align*}

I'm now looking for the proof of the Laplace transform of **real number** powers, rather than just positive integer powers. I've been unable to find this in my research.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} \{ t^\alpha \} 
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} t^\alpha\ dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-w} \left(\dfrac{w}{s}\right)^\alpha\ \dfrac{dw}{s}\\
&= \dfrac{1}{s^{\alpha+1}}\int_0^\infty e^{-w} w^\alpha\ dw\\
&= \dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{s^{\alpha+1}}
\end{align*}
where $s>0$

Comment: Can you please explain what's going on here?

Comment: Did you want this or another thing?

Comment: I meant a worded explanation.

Comment: this is Laplace definition, used to $t^\alpha$.

Comment: But what is $\alpha$ and how does this differ from the proof for positive integer powers?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a real number .

Comment: @ThePointer This computation is making use of the definition of the gamma function:
$$
\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1}\ \mathsf dt
$$